# A switch connected to a router

Tags: networking, router, switch

So the router, with 3 other computers connected on it, is connected to a switch with 3 other computers connected to it, all the computers are getting internet but they cant seem to find the computers that are connected with the other device, such as the computers on the router just find the others computers on the router and the same happens to the devices on the switch.

This is a problem because we need constant transference of files between all the computers.
If i need to give anymore information please just say so.

The network is more or less like this [A diagram of how all the devices are connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR3us.png)

Comment: some switches and routers have (or in the past have had) a designated "uplink" port, often port 1. Many (or most) new devices are auto-sensing and can handle this, but check your documentation for both devices. Also, I once had an ISP-provided router that had a bug where it would decide to stop communicating with the connected switch, requiring me to unplug the cable briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the router's WAN is the internet gateway, and the switch is on the LAN side of the router; all PCs need to be in the same subnet (192.168.1.x/24). You can probably configure DHCP in the router to serve IP addresses to everything.